# Block incoming traffic at home via static IP

Tags: networking, router

I have a static IP to be whitelisted on a number of services I have to use from home.

However this means that my home router is now accessible by the web, ftp etc.

My routers firewall (ASUS DSL-G31) only allows blocking of specific IP addresses but I want to prevent all incoming traffic request to the IP, or at least ones that may be attempting to access my router an local machines via the router.

Is there anything else I can do apart from get a better router (suggestions!), my ISP can't help.

Obviously I have the router password set but that could be hacked over time I'm sure.

These are the settings I'm trying in my Firewall

```
Source IP    
*.*.*.* 

Port Range
1:65535

Destination IP
82.555.80.168

Port Range
80

Protocol
TCP
```

Where 82.555.80.168 would be my static IP.

Comment: I don't understand, do you host the services or are you trying to access services which need your IP white-listed? If the latter then there's no reason to have inbound ports open, so just block inbound traffic on 80, 20, etc.

Comment: It's the latter but my route firewall is very basic and asks for an IP for each rule, i.e block only certain IP's

Comment: See the settings I'm trying in the edited question

Comment: I'm very unclear about what you're asking. Are you asking if your syntax is correct or if your approach is correct, or if you are blocking the correct ports?

Comment: All of the above, I don't know if what I'm asking makes sense. All I know is my router login is available via the web and I want that inaccessible, it seems these settings are the only way to do that.